# Firebase Functions not able to use oncall functions in app, returns internal error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

## Firebase Functions onCall not working

I was recently following the Firebase tutorial series by **The Net Ninja** YouTube channel.

---

#### [The Net Ninja Firebase Function Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i_aLkr62adUTJi53y7OjOf)

[Firebase Functions Tutorial #5 - Callable Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mL1VuiL5Kk&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i_aLkr62adUTJi53y7OjOf&index=5&t=315s)

---

And I got stuck in the firebase functions part, first I was not even able to deploy them because billing was enabled in my account, then I put the node version in the package.json to '8', it didn't ask for billing when I deployed the functions.

> *package.json*

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

earlier it was
`"node": "10"`

After this, I'm able to deploy the functions and even run an **onRequest** function, but not the **onCall** function.
Whenever I try to call an **onCall** function, I don't know what happens, maybe I get an error I'm not sure.

> *index.js* firebase function file

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.randomNumber = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const number = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    console.log(number);
    response.send(number.toString());
});

exports.sayHello = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log('its running');
    return 'hello, ninjas';
});
```

The *randomNumber* runs perfectly, but **sayHello** never runs or whatever.
I'm calling the **sayHello** function from frontend

> *app.js* my web app's javascript file

```js
//sayHello function call
const button = document.querySelector('.call');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //get firebase function reference
    const sayHello = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sayHello');
    sayHello().then(result => {
        console.log(result.data);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

I'm also initializing firebase properly in the index.html

```html
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

In the console of my web app, something gets logged

```
Error: internal
    at new y (error.ts:66)
    at w (error.ts:175)
    at A.<anonymous> (service.ts:245)
    at tslib.es6.js:100
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at r (tslib.es6.js:71)
```

Can anyone at least tell what this console log means???

---

Please help, not able to complete the tutorial series after which I'll move on to some real projects, been stuck at this for a week now.
Thanks in advance, if can solve my problem.

---

---

## Solution found

---

Just downgrade the javascript sdk version you are using in your front end to 7.21.0, that's it, it'll work.

The issue was as stated by *@DougStevenson* below that Firebase callable functions, at the current time (Oct 2020) is not working with javascript sdk 7.21.1 and 7.22.0.

[Cannot invoke HttpsCallable functions anymore after upgrading to firebase 7.22.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3890)

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.21.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.21.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.21.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.21.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found that callable functions from javascript web clients are broken with SDK version 7.21.1.  If you downgrade to 7.21.0, it should work OK.  The latest 7.22.0 still seems broken.

This has been [filed on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3890) if you want to track it.

**Update Oct 5, 2020**: Apparently this has been fixed in 7.22.1.

Comment: yeah, I tried it, downgraded it to 7.21.0 and it just worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson i was about to commit sucide. I had an Electron App and was moving it to Web with Firebase hosting and just wanted to move all my HTTP trigger funcs to callable ones... have been scratching my head for 3 days.. was about to rollback all changes to http triggger and saw this ... :)

Comment: I want to add a note here if you experience this, you may also need to update the `firebase-functions` package on the server side.  This causes the same issue; resolved by updating to the latest.